# Two-deep optional property

Tags: swift

1. This line:

   `cell.imageView?.setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: message.imageFile?.url?))`

causes this XCode warning on the last optional `.url?`:

```
Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

2. When I change it to this:

   `if let url = message.imageFile?.url {
           cell.imageView?.setImageWithURL(NSURL(string:url))
    }`

There is no compiler error. It's unwrapped, and I understand this. However,  I don't understand why the first attempt won't compile. Shouldn't `message.imageFile?.url?` just return `nil` if either `imageFile?` or `url?` are `nil`?

---

OBJC METHODS IN SWIFT CODE
`setImageWithURL` is an ObjC method from the AFNetworking library with the signature:

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url;
```

Is this the problem? When using this method in Swift is the `url` parameter converted to a non-optional? Therefore I can't pass in `nil`?

Answer (score 1):

`NSURL` requires that the `string` parameter be non-nil, so you can't pass in an optional value, which is what you are doing in the first snippet.  `message.imageFile?.url` returns an optional value because it is the result of a method called as part of an optional chain (`?.`).  Anything returned after the `?` in an optional chain will be optional.

Unwrapping with an if-let binding provides you with a `url` property that is non-nil, and thus can be used without a problem as a parameter to `NSURL`'s initializer, as you are doing in the second snippet.